# Pandas Rolling: How to roll from left to right or from up to down?

Tags: python, pandas

As default, I have a question that I am using the `Pandas.DataFrame.rolling()` method. And I find the method only calculate the value according to the previous number or the center number of this value. And now I need to get value according to the later number. Such as:

```
import pandas as pd
datas = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3]})
datas["c"] = datas["a"].rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean()
```

datas:

```
   a    c
0  1  1.0
1  2  1.5
2  3  2.5
```

How can I get datas, such as:

```
   a    c
0  1  1.5
1  2  2.5
2  3  3.0
```

I would be grateful if anyone could answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the column by calling `.iloc[::-1]` before rolling:

```
datas["c"] = datas["a"].iloc[::-1].rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean()
```

This would give you the wanted dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the dataframe and do the rolling.

```
datas = datas[::-1]
datas['c'] = datas.rolling(2,min_periods=1).mean()
datas=datas[::-1]
```

You will get the output.